# unable to push changes to cpanel-hosted repo

Tags: laravel, git, github, cpanel, jail-shell

I'm trying to set up a cpanel-hosted repository to make continuous deployment with a laravel project, which is also hosted in a github repository. The goal is to use a subdomain as a test server (like xampp on my pc) in order to work with the same environment as the shared hosting server I have for production.

The issue comes when I have to push changes to the cpanel repo. I have followed some steps in order to reach this point:

- Created an empty repository from cpanel's git version control
- Clone github's repository to my computer
- Added cpanel repo as a remote to the local repository
- execute `git config receive.denycurrentbranch updateInstead` on cpanel repo (via ssh)
- execute `git push -u cpanel Development --exec=/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git-receive-pack` on local repo to push all files and changes. Where `cpanel` is the remote and `Development` is the branch's name on my local repo

After this, I get the following:

```
jailshell: C:/Program: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I really don't understand why I'm getting this issue, I've attempted to do it these ways:

- Create an empty repo on cpanel / clone cpanel repo to local / fetch github repo / push to cpanel repo from local
- Clone repo to cpanel / clone cpanel repo to local / push changes to cpanel repo from local

and all of them took me to the same error in console. Is there a way to set up a cpanel repo to make continuous integration?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't use Windows, but `C:/Program` looks like something took `C:\Program Files\more path parts\another directory\file.ext` and broke it up at the spaces. This is the right thing to do on a Unix-like system (Linux etc), and quite often the *wrong* thing to do on Windows. That's probably the place to start.

Comment: So where should I review the error?

Comment: I don't know. `jailshell` is the one that printed the message, so maybe jailshell misread the file name. I don't have or use any of this software though. It's your problem, not mine :-)